# Query on ? in regular expression - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a query on `?` in RegEx of Javascript.
The explanation for this is given as **Matches zero or one occurrences**. Can you please see the below screenshot from RegExPal and help me explain the functionality?

[image]

In the above picture, even though the upper case characters are mentioned, why they are failed to get selected? Now see the below picture, I just swapped the order and I can see the selection. Can you please explain?

[image]

Comment: BTW, `/[A-Z]?/g` selects `ABC` [regardless](https://regexr.com/4tb4l) of [position](https://regexr.com/4tb4i).

Comment: ? Quantifier indicates matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible. So position should not matter here. Please use right regex checking tool as your point is right.  [Working demo on another REGEX checking site](https://regex101.com/r/dGZwLj/3)

Comment: Might be there is a bug in the website I am referring.